# How do you disable FFmpeg from accessing remote files over HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a compilation option that forces FFmpeg to only be able to access local files?  If a user of my system specifies some kind of malicious input file (like an HLS manifest) which points to some arbitrary location on the Internet, I don't want FFmpeg to follow that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a compilation option that forces FFmpeg to only be able to access local files?

`--disable-network` to disable network support.

Additional, related options:

- `--disable-protocol=NAME` to disable a particular protocol.
- `--disable-protocols` to disable **all** protocols, followed by `--enable-protocol=file,pipe` to only enable the *file* and *pipe* protocols for example.

See `./configure --help` for more info.